# Smooth page scrolling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a script to scroll pages when menu buttons are clicked, similar effect like: http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll

```
var m1 = document.getElementById('m1'),
    m2 = document.getElementById('m2'),
    m3 = document.getElementById('m3'),
    m4 = document.getElementById('m4'),
    m5 = document.getElementById('m5'),
    m2PositionY = document.getElementById('id2').offsetTop,
    m3PositionY = document.getElementById('id3').offsetTop,
    doneValue = true,
    windowPageYOffset = 0;

function Scroll(ScrollValue1) {
    windowPageYOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    if(windowPageYOffset == ScrollValue1) {
        doneValue = true;
    }
    // scroll up
    else if(windowPageYOffset >= ScrollValue1) {
        window.scrollBy(0, -(1 + ((windowPageYOffset - ScrollValue1) / 10)));
    }
    // scroll down
    else {
        window.scrollBy(0, 1 + ((ScrollValue1 - windowPageYOffset) / 10));
    }
    if(windowPageYOffset != ScrollValue1) {
        var setTimeoutScrollValue1 = setTimeout('Scroll(' + ScrollValue1 + ')', 20);
    }
}

function doneOrNot(doneOrNotValue1) {
    if(doneValue && doneOrNotValue1 != windowPageYOffset) {
        Scroll(doneOrNotValue1);
        doneValue = false;
    }
}
m1.onclick = function () {
    doneOrNot(0); // no need for a id since top is allways 0
}
m2.onclick = function () {
    doneOrNot(m2PositionY);
}
m3.onclick = function () {
    doneOrNot(m3PositionY);
}
```

I am using a "true or false variable" (`doneValue`) to determine if previous `Scroll` is finished before next can start. I wonder if there is any better method to do this in JavaScript?

Please give other feedback if you have any :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things you can do differently

1. Animations are most often accomplished by getting the difference between start and end values, and animating a factor from zero to 1. Multiply that with the difference, and you get an offset.
2. Instead of relying on an interval (which may be slow, since JS is single-threaded), most animation libraries compare the start time to the current time, to see how far along the animation should be.
3. Instead of waiting for the animation to stop and a boolean to flip, you can clear the animation's timer, and forcibly stop the animation, before starting a new one. That way the user's clicks aren't ignored, but override previous clicks instead.

Here's an alternative implementation using that approach and other good stuff:

```
var smoothScrollTo = (function () {
  var timer, start, factor;

  return function (target, duration) {
    var offset = window.pageYOffset,
        delta  = target - window.pageYOffset; // Y-offset difference
    duration = duration || 1000;              // default 1 sec animation
    start = Date.now();                       // get start time
    factor = 0;

    if( timer ) {
      clearInterval(timer); // stop any running animation
    }

    function step() {
      var y;
      factor = (Date.now() - start) / duration; // get interpolation factor
      if( factor >= 1 ) {
        clearInterval(timer); // stop animation
        factor = 1;           // clip to max 1.0
      } 
      y = factor * delta + offset;
      window.scrollBy(0, y - window.pageYOffset);
    }

    timer = setInterval(step, 10);
    return timer; // return the interval timer, so you can clear it elsewhere
  };
}());
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/1/)

Another advantage of always animating a factor between zero and 1 is that you can run it through other expressions, and (for instance) animated the scroll with a sine wave.

Comment: I [refactored](http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/2/) out the general animation logic from the specific act of scrolling and added support for easing functions.

Comment: And added back in the canceling animation functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/3/

Comment: Very nice, but it seems you're assigning `change = to - from` _before_ you've checked the `from` and `to` arguments. I think you're going to get some NaN-nonsense there if you omit the `from` and `to` args but include an easing function.

Comment: [Good catch](http://jsfiddle.net/DruwJ/4/)

Comment: Thank you both so much! It looks really good! I have much to learn... Some questions: What does this "window.smoothScrollTo = function (...) {}" differ from "function smoothScrollTo(target, duration)"? Bill, can you show me a working example with easing out function?

Comment: @user1087110 `function xyz() ...` and `xyz = function () ...` are equivalent - no difference whatsoever. The reason I'm using `window.smoothScrollTo` in the demo is just to ensure that the function is available globally. This is generally _not_ a good idea. I just did it for demo-purposes, but it's bad practice to pollute the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out! Also I don't understand "animation(function (position) { window.scroll(0,position); }, duration, start, target);"?

Comment: @user1087110 the `animation` function simply animates a number's value over a certain duration. The way Bill set it up, the `animation` function, calls a function you provide with the value as an argument, each time it updates. In this case, the function provided scrolls the window, but it could just as easily move an element  or do something else. Passing a function to another function is a common javascript technique, so you'll see it again.

Comment: Please note that neither of the code snippets posted above use requestAnimationFrame, which has many advantages over using setInterval - see http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ and other resources elsewhere online (many linked at the bottom of the article)